# Separating XML products by Category in PHP

Tags: php, json, xml

I read an XML file in PHP by

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("./files/downloaded.xml");
```

This file is having many products with different categories.
I want to separate them with respect to their categories.
Here is the look of the read file view by the following code.

```
print "<pre>";
print_r($xml);
print "</pre>";
```

[image]

I separated the products by the following code

```
$baby = array();
for($x=0;$x < count($xml->product); $x++)
  {
      if( preg_match("#Groceries > ([ a-zA-Z0-9]+) >#i",$xml->product[$x]->category,$match) )
      {
        $match[1] = str_replace(" ", "" , strtolower($match[1]) );
        if($match[1] == "baby"){
            $baby[] = $xml->product[$x];
        }

      }
  }
```

and it has been separated in an array named as $baby and here is the view of the baby array by the following code

```
print "<pre>";
print_r($baby);
print "</pre>";
```

[image]
Now I want to save this as baby.xml and baby.json file but I don't know how to save this.
I tried this code to save these files

```
$baby_json = simplexml_load_string($baby);
$json = json_encode($baby_json);
file_put_contents("./files/foodcupobard.json",$json);
file_put_contents("./files/foodcupobard.xml",$baby);
```

But it is not working after separation.
Here is the code which works before separation

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("./files/downloaded.xml");
$xml_json = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$json = json_encode($xml_json);
file_put_contents("./files/baby.json",$json);
file_put_contents("./files/baby.xml",$xml);
```

The reason it is not working after separation is that after separation {$baby} becomes an array instead of SimpleXMLElement Object. Can anyone help me to save these separated products into an baby.xml and baby.json files ? or any other way to separate these products with php code ?

Any Help would be much appreciated!
Thanks :)

Comment: please edit your question and type the relevant parts of your xml instead of linking an image. The image on an external server may be deleted in the future, and your question will be useless for other developers then.

Comment: Yes, please post actual xml or php output. Would like to help but don't have a reproducible example here.

Answer (score 1):

Manipulate the original `SimpleXml` object instead of creating an array.
Then save as XML with `$xml->asXML($filename);`

Use `xpath` to select `<product>` nodes with a certain `<category>`. `xpath` is like SQL for XML:

```
/products/product[starts-with(category, 'Foo > Bar >')]
```

Comments:

- expression will return all `<product>` having a `<category>` starting with `"Foo > Bar >"`
- `[]` enclose a condition.
- you could use the `contains` function instead of `start-with`

code example:

```
$products = $xml->xpath("/products/product[starts-with(category, 'Foo > Bar >')]");
```

**BUT** `$products` is an array of `SimpleXml` elements, but no `SimpleXml` object, so `asXML()` won't work here.

### Solution 1:

- select all `<product>` that are **`NOT`** in the desired category
- delete those from `$xml`
- save with `asXML()`

code example:

```
$products = $xml->xpath("/products/product[not(starts-with(category, 'Foo > Bar >'))]");

foreach ($products as $product)
    unset($product[0]);
```

This is the *self-reference-technique* to delete a node with `unset`.

show the manipulated XML:

```
echo $xml->asXML();
```

see it working: https://eval.in/512140

### Solution 2

Go with the original `$products` and build a new XML string from it.

```
foreach ($products as $product) 
    $newxmlstr = $newxmlstr . $product->asXML();

$newxmlstr = "<products>" . $newxmlstr . "</products>";
```

see it working: https://eval.in/512153

I prefer solution 1. XML manipulation by string functions carry the risk of error. If the original XML is really large, solution 2 might be faster.